# Java ActionListeners including information

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have a program where I want to click buttons and have them carry information to their actionListeners. It is a library program and the user clicks on a book image that opens a new JFrame with the information about that specific book. How can I make the information that is displayed individually based on which button is pressed? (I want a universal actionListener instead of individual ones because I have over 200 books.)

Comment: This seems like a very basic question that a little research would have solved. The [oracle tutorial on using buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) covers this.

Answer (score 0):

## You could...

Use a `Map` keyed to the button, which links the value to it.  So when the button is clicked, you would use the `JButton` as the key and ask the `Map` for the associated value

Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details...

## You could...

Create a simple, custom `ActionListener` which took the "book" as a reference, that would be capable of performing the required action when clicked, but which is customised for an individual book...

Something like...

```
public class BookActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    private Book book;
    public BookActionHandler(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        BookFrame bookFrame = new BookFrame(book); 
        //...
        bookFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then you could create your buttons something like...

```
for (Book book : listOfBooks) {
    JButton btn = new JButton(book.getTitle());
    btn.addActionListener(new BookActionHandler(book));
    //...
}
```

## You could...

Use the `Action` API to associate a given "book" with the button, allowing the `Action` to configure the button as well as providing it the means to perform the required action when the button is clicked...

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details...

Something like...

```
public class BookActionHandler extends AbstractAction {
    private Book book;
    public BookActionHandler(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
        putValue(NAME, book.getTitle());
        putValue(LARGE_ICON_KEY, book.getIcon());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        BookFrame bookFrame = new BookFrame(book); 
        //...
        bookFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then you could create your buttons something like...

```
for (Book book : listOfBooks) {
    JButton btn = new JButton(new BookActionHandler(book));
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so I'll post here in case anyone else has the same issue:

```
    class BookListener implements ActionListener{
        public Book myBook;
        public BookListener(Book b) {
            this.myBook = b;
        }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

You just have to insert this into the class definition and when calling the actionListener:

```
    bookButton.addActionListener(new BookListener(b));
```